# How to print 10K, 20K....1M in the xlabel of matplotlib plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hi I am working with RL and I want to plot the rewards for n time steps. For suppose if I have 1 Million time steps I'll be having the same no of rewards. Now when I plot it the x label gets messier. I would like the xlabel to show like 10K, 20K to 1M. How should I do this?

for e.g. I have this code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

x = torch.rand(1000000,)
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

so when you plot this, on the x-axis you will get 0, 200000, 400000, 600000, 800000, 1000000
But I would like to print display it as 20K, 40K, 60K, 80K, 1M

Comment: sure have edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an adaption of [Jake VanderPlas's custom ticks](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html) (he writes in multiples of π).

```
from math import log10, floor
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def format_func(value, tick_number=None):
    num_thousands = 0 if abs(value) < 1000 else floor (log10(abs(value))/3)
    value = round(value / 1000**num_thousands, 2)
    return f'{value:g}'+' KMGTPEZY'[num_thousands]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([500, 2_000], [2_200_000, 4_000_000])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(format_func))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(format_func))
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html), for example:

```
plt.xticks([0,200000,400000,600000,800000,1000000], 
           ["0", "200K", "400K", "600K", "800K", "1M"])
```